# Error when comparing input to character in assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to take an input which is either the character f or c. Then depending on that print out a message, however, when I try to compare the value that I have stored inside of the variable for the input value (conv) it doesn't produce the expected result and I can't figure out why. I'll attach the code for that specific part below and explain the output.

```
;Read and store the user input
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, conv  
    mov edx, 4 
    int 0x80


;Output the letter entered
 mov eax, 4
 mov ebx, 1
 mov ecx, conv
 mov edx, 4
 int 80h
 
 cmp ecx,66h ;comparing with ascii char that has hex val 66h i.e 'f'
 je toFarenheit

toCelcius:
    ;display test message for C
    mov edx, lenTestC    ;message length
    mov ecx, testMsgC    ;message to write
    mov ebx, 1      ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax, 4      ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
    jmp exit  

 toFarenheit:
    ;display test message for F
    mov edx, lenTestF    ;message length
    mov ecx, testMsgF    ;message to write
    mov ebx, 1      ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax, 4      ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

exit:
        mov eax, 1      ;system call number (sys_exit)
        int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .bss
res resb 4
conv resb 4
```

Although what's in ecx is the input which is f and it's being compared to 66h which is also f it doesn't evaluate to true for the je statement so doesn't jump to Fahrenheit so the toCelcius block runs and then the program jumps to exit and then it ends.

Comment: `cmp byte [conv], 'f'` maybe

Comment: @ecm yh that worked cheers for that it was taking me forever. If you want send it as an answer and I can mark it as solved

Comment: @ecm I've noticed a problem when I have numbers that are greater than 99 then it just doesn't work like before do you know why

Comment: I don't see anything in your question that deals with any numbers. Open a new question with the relevant code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in `ecx` or the low byte `cl` do not correspond to any ASCII codepoints. The value in `ecx` is used to pass a pointer to memory to the syscalls. Therefore the ASCII code can be found in the first byte of the `conv` buffer. Furthermore, you don't have to convert the letter to the numeric code yourself, NASM allows specifying the letter in single quotemarks to automatically insert the numeric code. Therefore your comparison should be as follows:

```
cmp byte [conv], 'f'
```